# Rails app is very slow with passenger + nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

My instance have 3.5GB memory and over 970MB are free. My rails app is very slow when started first time. I need to restart the nginx again. Any suggestion? Something wrong with my configuration?

This is my configuration for passenger + nginx

```
user user;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 10240;
}
worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;

http {


        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 900m;
        large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;



        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;



        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##
        passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /home/azureuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1/ruby;
        passenger_log_level 2;
        passenger_debug_log_file /var/log/nginx/passenger-error.log;
        passenger_spawn_method smart;
        passenger_pool_idle_time 1000;
        passenger_max_preloader_idle_time 0;
        passenger_max_requests 5000;
        passenger_pre_start http://api.mytjacket.com;



        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;
            root /home/user/apps/project-name/current/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            proxy_buffers 8 16k;
            proxy_buffer_size 32k;
            passenger_buffers 8 16k;
            passenger_buffer_size 32k;

            location /websocket {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:port/websocket;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Flying Passenger feature: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/flying_passenger.html